# How to only allow paste action in inputTextField in react native and disable cut/copy actions from context menu

Tags: react-native

I want to only allow paste action upon long press on text selection in inputTextField but I don't want to allow cut and copy action.
There is one attribute `contextMenuHidden` but it also blocks paste action along with copy and cut.
How can I achieve this behaviour ?
searching on chatGPT shows that there is two attributes `onCopy` and `onCut` events but I'm not sure those are right as I can't find those mentions in official [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having careful research, I found no solution for this but there is one hacky workaround!

logic is to set the cursor programatically at the end point whenever user tries to select text of size 1 to any.

Add following initialization for selection variable in class state:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selection: { start: 0, end: 0 },
    };
  }
```

Add following helper function:

```js
  handleSelectionChange = (event) => {
    console.log('Selection changed:', event.nativeEvent.selection);
    if (event.nativeEvent.selection.start !== event.nativeEvent.selection.end) { // Checking if cursor's starting and ending point are different, if it is then it implies user selected some text of length 1 or more.
      console.log('text got selected');
      this.setState({ selection: { start: event.nativeEvent.selection.end, end: event.nativeEvent.selection.end } });  //setting cursor at the end point of the text
    }
    else {
      this.setState({ selection: { start: event.nativeEvent.selection.start, end: event.nativeEvent.selection.end } });  //if cursor's starting and ending point are same then leaving it as it is.
    }
  }
```

Add following `onSelectionChange` and `selection` property in TextInput:

```js
<TextInput
  onSelectionChange={this.handleSelectionChange}
  selection={this.state.selection}
/>
```

However, this is not a proper solution but surely does the job!